# Is there a way to programmatically trigger a touch event at a point given on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touch-event

I would like to programmatically trigger a touch event at a point on the screen.  Do you know how to do this?

For example, I would like to click a UIView, then it should check to see if certain conditions are right, and if they aren't, then I will call setUserInteractionEnabled to NO, and then fire another event at the same point, so that the point goes through the view and to the next. Then the user interaction will be re-enabled.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   checking conditions if conditions are right.
    {[self setUserInteractionEnabled: NO];

   //fire another touch event at the same point so it goes through this view

     [self setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
 }
```

Comment: what you want to achive..explain in detail with example

Comment: how could you call touch event programatically touch can only be mannual(physical).

Comment: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't operate touch event programatically, instead I have another option to suggest you that will work the same you want.

**Alternative**:

You can take timer, which will be called after your desired time. In that you can call a function that will contain the data that you want to include in touch event. You can check your conditions and do y our other stuff accordingly.